# Gerar arquivo .txt com PHP com "til" (~) etc

Tags: php, txt

Não estou conseguindo gerar um arquivo .txt onde o til e acentos sejam impressos de forma correta. estou usando o `fwrite`.

trecho do código:

```
$arquivo  = fopen('aaa.txt', 'w+');
$escrever = fwrite($arquivo, $txt);

fclose($arquivo);
```

Comment: já tentou utf8_encode($txt)?

Comment: o aqurivo php, deve estar em  algum formato que não seja UTF-8, abra o arquivo em  um editor como  notePad++ e mude o formato para UTF-8 sem BOM, e verique se há oustros arquivos no include se tiver eles também  devem  estar no mesmo  formato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi!
O problema era mudar para mysqli_set_charset($conexao, 'iso-8859-1');
na conexão com o banco de dados!
Coisa básica e simples que tomou meu tempo.